# How to read a .graph file using python or networkx?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I want to read a .graph file that looks like this :

```
name node
000 node1
001 node2
002 node3
003 node4
```

I am using `networkx` and I haven't found any function that can help me.
Do, I have to parse it myself ?

Comment: what do name and node denote? Do you require both or just a single field will suffice?

Answer (score 0):

You can use snap libraries. If you have installed it, write `import snap` at first.
Then you can directly load this file by `G = snap.TUNGraph.Load(snap.TFIn("Filename.graph"))`.